# Date Time Manipulation in R

Tags: r, datetime, datetime-format

My dataset have a column named created_at, as follow:

```
**created_at** 

Tue Feb 21 14:14:34 UTC 2017  
Wed Feb 22 00:00:12 UTC 2017

...
```

I want to format it to DateTime and also extract the individual information, i.e, extract individual columns for weekday, month, day, time and year.

I try something like:

```
date_b <- str_split(amt$created_at, " ")

week <- as.data.frame(sapply(date_b, "[", 1))
month <- as.data.frame(sapply(date_b, "[", 2))
day <- as.data.frame(sapply(date_b, "[", 3))
year <- as.data.frame(sapply(date_b, "[", 6))
hour <- as.data.frame(sapply(date_b, "[",4))  

aux1 <- strptime(hora[,1], format="%H:%M:%S")
```

without luck.

Any help, please?

Ricardo.

Comment: have you taken a look at the `lubridate` package?

Comment: `strptime('Tue Feb 21 14:14:34 UTC 2017', format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y')`

Comment: Hi jaap. I used the piece of code you post and got a large POSIXlt of NA's.

Comment: Thanks for `lubridate` Craig. Will be useful. Thanks.

Comment: @RicardoSilva See `example("strptime")` One has to set `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")`

Comment: @jogo Thanks for that. `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")` was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strptime requires exact matching of format

```
> test <- "Wed Feb 22 00:00:12 UTC 2017"
> strptime(test, "%a %b %d %T UTC %Y", tz = "GMT")
[1] "2017-02-22 00:00:12 GMT"
```

To extract specific values I tend to use separate() in tidyr, for example

```
> col1 = c("a", "b")
> col2 = c("Tue Feb 21 14:14:34 UTC 2017", "Wed Feb 22 00:00:12 UTC 2017")
> col3 = c("test", "test2")

> df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3)

> df

  col1                         col2  col3
1    a Tue Feb 21 14:14:34 UTC 2017  test
2    b Wed Feb 22 00:00:12 UTC 2017 test2

> df %>% 
    separate(col2, 
             into = c("Weekday", "Month", "Date", "Time", "Timezone", "Year"),
             sep = " ",
             remove = FALSE)

  col1                         col2 Weekday Month Date     Time Timezone Year  col3
1    a Tue Feb 21 14:14:34 UTC 2017     Tue   Feb   21 14:14:34      UTC 2017  test
2    b Wed Feb 22 00:00:12 UTC 2017     Wed   Feb   22 00:00:12      UTC 2017 test2
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Eventually do `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")` (from `example("strptime")`)

Comment: @JPHwang I follow your example: `dados %>% 
  separate(dt, 
           into = c("Dia da Semana", "Mês", "Dia", "Hora", "Timezone", "Ano"),
           sep = " ",
           remove = FALSE)` and got: `Warning message:
Too few values at 103364 locations: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, ... `.  After `strptime` my dt column become '2017-02-21 13:09:50`. Any hint?

Comment: Try doing the the separate before the strptime? Since after the strptime the sep by " " will only yield two columns "2017-02-21" and "13:09:50", I believe that's why it's saying too few values (since you asked it to separate into 6 columns).